# Amend tabular environment in preamble: different font

Tags: tables, fonts, preamble

I'd like to put some lines in the preamble *to change the font of all tabulars in the document*. I know that I can easily define my own environment »mytabular«. But for different reasons I need to change tabular. I thought about simply adding (see MWE below) code to the macro, unfortunately without success.

```
\documentclass{article}

    \makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro\tabular\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

This is some text.

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lr}
  Hello! & 1234 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Those tabulars will be used outside floats, so it does not help to change something in the table environment.

Comment: have you looked at the `etoolbox`?

Comment: @cmhughes No. Unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge about TeX and its primitives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\Tabular\tabular
\let\endTabular\endtabular
\renewcommand\tabular{\sffamily\Tabular}
\renewcommand\endtabular{\endTabular\normalfont}

\begin{document}
This is some text.

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{lr}
  Hello! & 1234 
\end{tabular}

foo
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

The [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) can help here; in particular, the command `AtBeginEnvironment` can be used

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
```

Here's the output, and a complete MWE to play with:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

\begin{tabular}{lr}
  Hello! & 1234 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for introducing `\AtBeginEnvironment`.

Comment: Or `\preto{\tabular}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}`, but one must know the definition of `tabular` for realizing this is possible.

Comment: Very useful solution both in answer and comment thank you, much favoured over chosen answer as much more user friendly.